# Selenium in Python How to use if else

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from linkedin_scraper import actions
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common import exceptions  
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from credentials import email,password

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome("driver/chromedriver", options=chrome_options)

# email = os.getenv("LINKEDIN_USER")
# password = os.getenv("LINKEDIN_PASSWORD")
actions.login(driver, email, password) # if email and password isnt given, it'll prompt in terminal

urls = open('C:/Users/reddy/AppsTek/scraping/LinkedIn Scraping/LinkedIn Scraping1/urls3.csv')
for u in urls:
    try:
        driver.get(u)
        companies = []
        element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('pv-profile-section__toggle-detail-icon')
        
        if element:
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
        _ = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "experience-section")))
        all_urls = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div > a")
        for elem in all_urls:
            text = elem.text
            company = elem.get_property('href')
            if "linkedin.com/company" in company:
                z = company + 'about/'
                companies.append(z)
        else:
            _ = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "experience-section")))
            all_urls = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div > a")
        
            for elem in all_urls:
                text = elem.text
                company = elem.get_property('href')
                if "linkedin.com/company" in company:
                    z = company + 'about/'
                    companies.append(z)
        
        print(companies)
    
    except:
        print('Nothing found')
```

The output is:

Nothing Found
Nothing Found

The urls3.csv are:
https://www.linkedin.com/in/satyanadella/
https://www.linkedin.com/in/jeffweiner08/

But I want first persons URLs and second persons all URLs till the end.
The element code is to click on Show 5 more experiences.

My expected output would be:

```
['https://www.linkedin.com/company/microsoft/about/', 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/uchicago/about/', 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/starbucks/about/', 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/fredhutch/about/']
['https://www.linkedin.com/company/linkedin/about/', 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/next-play-ventures/about/', 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/concreterosecapital/about/', 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/intuit/about/', 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/donorschoose/about/', 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/everfi/about/', 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/bgcpeninsula/about/', 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/venture-for-america/about/', 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/malaria-no-more/about/', 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/accel-vc/about/', 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/linkedin/about/', 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/next-play-ventures/about/', 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/concreterosecapital/about/', 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/intuit/about/', 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/donorschoose/about/', 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/everfi/about/', 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/bgcpeninsula/about/', 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/venture-for-america/about/', 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/malaria-no-more/about/', 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/accel-vc/about/', 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/yahoo/',
```

'https://www.linkedin.com/company/warner-bros.-studios/about/',
'https://www.linkedin.com/company/braxton-associates/about/']

Comment: could you provide your expected output, please.

Comment: Okay, I gave @HedgeHog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time you use try except, try to make use of the exception error that's being thrown instead of just silently handling it. In your case you were getting a `NoSuchElementException` and you didn't see it.

To handle that exception you can use `find_elements_by_class_name` instead of `find_element_by_class_name` that returns a list and check if that list includes any elements. Slight modifications fixed your code.

```
...
element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('pv-profile-section__toggle-detail-icon')
if len(element) != 0:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element[0])
...
```

Comment: Hey thanks, it worked but in https://www.linkedin.com/in/jeffweiner08/ there is again Show 5 more experiences after when it gets clicked once. How do I click that again and scrape rest of the URLs?

Comment: @AkileshReddy You can handle that in a loop and as long as there is a button you keep clicking and scraping ?

Comment: Ya cool but I was getting error like TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable, can you write that for loop.

Comment: `element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('pv-profile-section__toggle-detail-icon')
for c in element:
      c.click() `
Even this is working but not getting all urls